# Connect a web service to a database and display information

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, web-services

I am a beginner VB.Net developer and wanted to know how to create a web service and connect this to an SQL 2012 database and display an item in a table. The database table has several fields including Stock Item, Manufacturer, Free Stock Quantity, Price, etc..

If I add a breakpoint and step through the code, I can see a value is passed into a string in the recordset and is returned, however, this isn't display properly. Obviously I've changed the server, username and password but thats the code shown below.

```
Public Class Service1
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

Private sqlconnection As ADODB.Connection

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function ShowStockItems() As String

    Dim Command As New SqlCommand

    sqlconnection = New ADODB.Connection
    sqlconnection.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=server;uid=id;pwd=password;database=Able_Instruments"
    Try
        sqlconnection.Open()
        Dim strReturn As String = ""
        Dim rstStockItem As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim strStockItem As String = "Select * from StockItem"
        rstStockItem.Open(strStockItem, sqlconnection)
        With rstStockItem
            If Not .BOF Then
                .MoveFirst()
                strReturn = .Fields.Item("TaxCodeID").Value
            End If![enter image description here][1]
        End With
        rstStockItem.Close()
        sqlconnection.Close()
        'Return strReturn
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
    End Try
End Function
End Class
```

I'm not sure if the problem is obvious but I'd like to be able to display an ID of a Stock Item and the Name of the Stock Item. For this example I used TaxCodeID to make sure the code was working correctly. Using Visual Studio 2010 and also have access to 2013 if need be.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWJ14.png

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I am not using Entity Framework I like to build classes for complexed data retrieval.

```
Public Class StockItem
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property ID As Integer
  'others as needed
End Class
```

Usage:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function ShowStockItems() As StockItem
 Dim _stockItem As New StockItem
 Dim Command As New SqlCommand
 sqlconnection = New ADODB.Connection
 sqlconnection.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=server;uid=id;pwd=password;database=Able_Instruments"
 Try
    sqlconnection.Open()
    Dim strReturn As String = ""
    Dim rstStockItem As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strStockItem As String = "Select * from StockItem"
    rstStockItem.Open(strStockItem, sqlconnection)
    With rstStockItem
        If Not .BOF Then
            .MoveFirst()
            _stockItem.ID = Convert.ToInt32(.Fields.Item("TaxCodeID").Value)
            _stockItem.Name = .Fields.Item("what field you need).Value
        End If
    End With
 Catch
 Finally
   rstStockItem.Close()
   sqlconnection.Close()
 End Try
 Return _stockItem
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, was great help!

Comment: If this fits as the answer then click the check mark and up vote if appropriate.